# gltf piepeline draco compression creates weird edges

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, gltf, react-fiber

I'm trying to compress a glb file with gltf pipeline module ( https://github.com/CesiumGS/gltf-pipeline )

The original glb file looks like the following:

[image]

I'm compressing glb model with the following script:

```
const getCompressedGltfFile = async (glb) => {
  try {
    const compressedFile = await processGlb(glb, {
      dracoOptions: {
        compressionLevel: 10,
      },
    });
    return compressedFile.glb;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("compressingGltfFile failed:", glb, error);
    return glb;
  }
};
```

After the compression, the model looks like the following:

[image]

Is there any way I can compress glb model without creating weird edges?

Comment: gltf pipeline has a range of options, but the only one specified above is `compressionLevel: 10` (i.e. most aggressive compression). Since we don't have the model you'll have to try these out yourself, but I'd suggest trying combinations of: lower compressionLevel, higher quantizeNormalBits, higher quantizePositionBits, and perhaps unified quantization.

Comment: I set 20 to quantizePositionBits and it fixed the issue!! Thank you so much!